# How to convert value of a map to vector in clojure

Tags: clojure

How do I convert value of a map to vector? For example:
`{:foo 1 :bar {:foo 1 :bar 2}}` to `{:foo 1 :bar [{:foo 1 :bar 2}]}`

Tried

```
(for [k (vector (keys m)) :let [m (assoc m :k (vector (:k m)) )] :when (isa? (class (:k m)) clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap) ] (:k m)) m)
```

But the map displays without any conversion.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
(into {} (for [[k v] m] [k (if (map? v) [v] v)]))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [postwalk](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/postwalk) to support nested maps.

```
 (use 'clojure.walk)
 (postwalk (fn [x]
             (if (map? x) (vector x) x))
          {:foo 1 :bar {:foo 1 :bar 2}})
```

Comment: I used this approach in the past... +1 daddy-o!

Answer (score 3):

zero323's solution is probably more efficient than mine, but since it can't hurt to know of multiple solutions, here's another in addition to those posted so far:

```
(zipmap (keys m) 
        (map #(if (map? %) (vector %) %) 
              (vals m)))
```